# TeXLive vs. MikTeX - an updated comparison

Tags: miktex, texlive, distributions, comparison

What are the **current** differences between MikTeX and TeXLive?
[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20036/67717) has many answers, but most of them are quite old, and it isn't clear what is still relevant, especially since MikTeX has undergone significant changes recently (notably - added support for Linux and macOS).
Please edit the first answer as community wiki, and add criteria for comparison. Feel free to add explanations regarding whether some criterion gives an advantage to one of the distributions

Comment: You are free to add new answers to that question but this is definitely a duplicate question that would  normally be closed as  duplicate.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as I wrote, that question has answers which ar >10 years old, and I didn't get an answer as to whether they are still relevant. And some are simply now false. These answers have many upvotes, so they appear on top. Is there another way to highlight the *current correct* answers?

Comment: But if you think it's better, I can move the updating answer to that question.

Comment: boooooo. This should not be closed as a duplicate. The old post is very clearly out-of-date, with the accepted answer being from _2011_ for christ's sake. This post's focus on 2023+ comparison is an entirely different question and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 4):

- **Supported operating system**

  - TeXLive: Linux, macOS, Windows
  - MikTeX: Linux, macOS, Windows
- **Open source**

  - TeXLive: Yes
  - MikTeX: Yes
- **Maintainer(s)**

  - TeXLive: TUG (TeX Users Group)
  - MikTeX: Christian Schenk
  - Note: Some consider this an advantage of TeXLive as it makes it more future-proof.
- **GUI for package installation**

  - TeXLive: Yes
  - MikTeX: Yes
- **On-the-fly package installation**

  - TeXLive: No
  - MikTeX: Yes
- **Update scheme**

  - TeXLive: Strict yearly releases
  - MikTeX: ?
- **Installation process**

  - TeXLive:
  - MikTeX:
- **[Criterion]**

  - TeXLive:
  - MikTeX:

Comment: The TeX Live binaries have yearly releases but updates of packages are usually available one or two days after the CTAN release. With MiKTeX it often takes a little longer, sometimes even a few weeks.

Comment: TeX Live has [`texliveonfly`](https://ctan.org/pkg/texliveonfly). I've never used it, because I prefer not to need internet everywhere and therefore always do a full installation.

Comment: TinyTeX provides on-the-fly package installation for texlive

Comment: @cabohah so I'll add a distinction between updates of binaries and packages.

Comment: I didn't know about the onthefly options (add-ons? Packages?) I'll check them out, thx

Comment: @cabohah texliveonfly was written in 2011 and not maintained since then... (can't check it myself atm as I'm using distro-maintaied TeXLive)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz if I understand correctly, TinyTeX is technically a LaTeX distro of it's own, not a part of TeXLive

Comment: @UrYa'ar tinytex uses texlive internally, it is basically a wrapper around it

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes but if someone has TeXLive on their machine, they can't just add tinytex to it, right? They need to replace TeXLive with tinytex