# Why is `\everypar` disturbed by a non-empty pair of brackets at the beginning of the following paragraph?

Tags: lists, noindent

At the end of a custom pseudo-list environment, I re-define `\@doendpe` to prevent indents in the paragraphs immediately following the environment, regardless on whether there is a blank line after the `\end{env}` (1st case) or not (2nd case). This works fine for most use cases (1st through 3rd cases).

However, if there is a non-empty pair of curly brackets at the beginning of the paragraph immediately following the environment, the no-indent spreads to the next paragraph as well (4th case). If the group is empty, it works as expected (5th case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent8mm
\author{}
\title{}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@doendpe\@doendpe
\newenvironment{mylist}
  {\list{}{%
      \leftmargin0pt
      \parindent0pt
      \bfseries\sffamily
    }\item\relax}
  {\endlist
   \gdef\@doendpe{%
     \@endpetrue
     \everypar{{\setbox\z@\lastbox}\everypar{}\@endpefalse}%
     \global\let\@doendpe\orig@doendpe}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
  1st case
\end{mylist}

test test test

test test test

test test test

\begin{mylist}
  2nd case
\end{mylist}
test test test

test test test

test test test

\begin{mylist}
  3rd case
\end{mylist}

[test test test]

test test test

test test test

\begin{mylist}
  4th case
\end{mylist}

{[}test test test{]}

test test test

test test test

\begin{mylist}
  5th case
\end{mylist}

{}test test test

test test test

test test test

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Rendered output of above code]

I'd like to know (1), why this solution breaks when there is a non-empty pair of brackets immediately after the `\end` (and why it doesn't break when the brackets are empty) and (2), what would I need to change in the *definition of the environment* to make it work with all five use cases.

Comment: Through some debugging (print out the value of everypar token list variable every time the code is executed, and every time it's set) I observe that after "everypar is set to nothing" the next time "value of everypar" is still nonempty, so I prefix `\global` to `\everypar` at both places and it fixes the issue... but I can't answer the question because I've no idea how `\@doendpe` works.

Comment: your braces mean that the begin of the paragraph where everypar is executed is inside a group and so the doendpe-everypar can't do its magic to reset itself.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "begin of the paragraph" meaning that there must be horizontal material? That's why empty braces have no effect since they don't cause a switch to h-mode and therefore don't "expand"(?) the `\everypar`, did i get that about right?

Comment: yes. You could read ltpara-doc.pdf. It explains quite nicely what is going on at the begin of the paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your braces in case 4 with the text in it mean that the paragraph is started in a group. In this group `\everypar` is executed and it does reset itself but only locally, and so after the group the "doendpe-everypar" magic to reset itself is lost again.

You could use a para hook instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent8mm
\author{}
\title{}


\newenvironment{mylist}
  {\list{}{%
      \leftmargin0pt
      \parindent0pt
      \bfseries\sffamily
    }\item\relax}
  {\endlist\AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\OmitIndent}}


\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
  1st case
\end{mylist}

test test test

test test test

test test test

\begin{mylist}
  2nd case
\end{mylist}
test test test

test test test

test test test

\begin{mylist}
  3rd case
\end{mylist}

[test test test]

test test test

test test test

\begin{mylist}
  4th case
\end{mylist}

{[}test test test{]}

test test test

test test test

\begin{mylist}
  5th case
\end{mylist}

{}test test test

test test test

test test test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that this requires a rather recent verison of LaTeX. In TL2019, this doesn't work (Undefined control sequence \AddToHookNext).

Comment: yes, the hook management in general and especially the para hooks are a recent addition and one of the reasons why it can pay off to invest some time and effort to update (and keep up-to-date) your tex system. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670578/2388

Comment: Although I now understand what the issue is from your and user202729's comments under the OP, would you mind to add a few lines on what exactly went wrong (question (1)) so I can flag your answer as "accepted"?