# What is better? KOMA script or memoir in 2023?

Tags: koma-script, memoir, books, update, comparison

To make a professional book layout, many people suggest to use either KOMA-Script or memoir.
It has been 13 years since the last question comparing them. What is better? KOMA or memoir. Has KOMA improved it's English documentation?

Comment: It'll depend on your target audience, the book, your typographic preferences, your experience and a lot of other things … Therefore this question will probably be closed as "opinion-based".

Comment: In addition to what Ingmar has already said, it would be advisable to rephrase your question on the basis of technical issues that could lead to a more quantitative comparison that would lead to more objective comparisons, otherwise your question will be closed.

Regarding documentation, if you check the current one, you will see the problem remains and the German documentation is better and clearer.

Comment: AFAIK some years ago the whole English manual has been revised by a native speaker. This should overcome the linguistic weaknesses that existed 13 years ago. The content should also be identical to the German edition by now. If you still find misleading wording or errors, I recommend [reporting](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/tickets/) them and suggesting appropriate improvements directly.

Comment: BTW: Instead of [asking more or less the same question again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7742/), IMHO it would be better to comment/update the existing answers to that question or add new answers.

Comment: I don't agree with all those trigger happy users here who closed your question. That said, you can't really compare LaTeX & Friends today with the software 10 years ago. There has been so much progress of Luatex, TikZ & friends, KOMA-script, LaTeX3, maybe look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670578/4736